# ClosedXML DataTable to Excel does not export the int(c#) values to Number(Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

Number Stored as Text warning!

Datatable is filled with values as the following;

```
  dr["Call Duration"] = arrayItem.duration;
  dr["Ring Duration"] = arrayItem.ring_time;
```

where duration is in int. However, the exported excel does not show the duration values in Number format. Excel Format example is shared below.
[image: Number stored as text warning]

```
    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt,"Sheet1");
```

Is there any method to make int or string values in Number format pre-export? Excel's VALUE function or Convert to Number are not options.

Saving the exported file is done like the following;

```
wb.SaveAs("datatable" + ".xlsx");
```

Comment: You could actually help us by describing how do these ints show up in Excel. Also where is the code that writes the DataTable to the worksheet? Perhaps the code does not take in the values because it is expecting Doubles? so do not try and write ints to Excel, instead convert to Double first

Comment: I have added the excel sample as you suggested, thanks. However, Convert.ToDouble(arrayItem.duration) gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick fix I had to make column headers throw exception the Text value could not be converted to Number. I have shared my final solution below.

```
wb.Worksheet("Sheet1").Column(2).CellsUsed(c => c.WorksheetRow().RowNumber() != 1).DataType = XLDataType.Number;
wb.Worksheet("Sheet1").Column(3).CellsUsed(c => c.WorksheetRow().RowNumber() != 1).DataType = XLDataType.Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the datatype of the cell/column.

An example:

```
ws.Cell(ro, co + 1).Value = "'123.45";
ws.Cell(ro, co + 1).DataType = XLDataType.Number;
```

You can find other example on ClosedXML documentation [here](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Data-Types)

Comment: Thank you for the direction. Looking forward to see your comments on performance.